# PHP empty session files generated by login system

Tags: php, session, cookies

Recently I've noticed that many blank sessions are being created, I'm not sure why though as I believe I'm doing everything the correct way.

At the moment we create a session when a user either **logs in** or **registers**, we then check whether a user is logged in with an `isset($_COOKIE['auth'])` that belongs to the session created during login or register.

If that cookie is present then we start a session, this helps us avoid starting thousands of sessions for unregistered users and creating a huge amount of session files.

**Session Settings:**

*php file*

```
session_save_path("/home/user/sessions");
session_set_cookie_params("86400", "/");
session_name("auth");
```

*php.ini*

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 90000
session.cookie_lifetime = 90000
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.use_only_cookies = 1
```

---

**Create Login Session** (On Successful login)

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);

$_SESSION['userId'] = $userId;
$_SESSION['created'] = time();

session_write_close();
header("Location: $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]");
```

---

**Checking whether a session should be resumed**

We then check whether to start a session or not for a user based on whether the `auth` session cookie is set.

It will only be set if the user has registered or logged in before:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['auth'])){
    session_start();
    session_write_close();
}
```

---

**Check if user is logged in**

To check if a user is logged in we then use a function:

```
function isAuthenticated(){

    if (!isset($_SESSION['userId']))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

---

**Log Out**

```
function logOut(){
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    setcookie('auth', "", 0);
    unset($_SESSION);
    unset($_COOKIE['auth']); 
    return true;
}
```

---

For some reason though I am getting lots of empty (filesize 0) session files in the session folder.

Where are these coming from?

Does `session_regenerate_id(true)` create a new session file and leave the old session file empty? That is the only reason I can think of for the empty session files?

Comment: Yes, it should be handled by the gc better, but if you call a function that creates a session id, you are creating a session. Just call session_destroy if they aren't authenticated.

Comment: Is `session.auto_start = 0` ?

Comment: You should consider changing `unset($_SESSION)` into an iteration via `foreach` unsetting each element separately . [The PHP documentation says](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php#refsect1-function.session-unset-notes) : "Caution: Do NOT unset the whole $_SESSION with unset($_SESSION) as this will disable the registering of session variables through the $_SESSION superglobal."

Comment: What can mean either, always consider either .. your functions seem to assume state, you always have to keep a virtual state, and always check .. always

Answer (score 2):

```
bool session_regenerate_id([bool $delete_old_session = false]);
```

view [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) for more information.

`session_regenerate_id()` will replace the current session id with a new one, and keep the current session information.

the old session file is kept and a new session file is generated every time that `session_register_id()` is ran. `session_register_id()` creates a new session with a new session_id but retains the old session information, so yes, your `session_register_id()` is keeping the old session files to null after updating the information to the new session file.

Comment: As you can see in manual, passing true to this function, will delete the old session file.

Answer (score 1):

> Does session_regenerate_id(true) create a new session file and leave
>   the old session file empty? That is the only reason I can think of for
>   the empty session files?

Calling `session_regenerate_id(true)` attempts to delete the session file but will return false if it fails to do (see relevant php source code below). For this reason I suggest you verify that your session functions run successfully i.e.

```
if(!session_start()) {
  //log error 
}

if(!session_regenerate_id(true)) {
  //log error
}
```

Also check your settings for how frequently your garbage collector runs. Perhaps it runs on a very low probability and you're seeing orphaned sessions accumulate. The settings below will run the garbage collector with 1/100 (1%) probability each time php runs. Try deleting all orphans by setting both values to 1 for a single run and then setting the values to 1/100 like below.

```
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 100
```

Finally, your logout method expires the session cookie on browser close. Try expiring it immediately instead

```
setcookie('auth', null, -1);
```

**PHP Source for session_regenerate_id**

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c

Note the call to `PS(mod)->s_destroy(&PS(mod_data), PS(id) TSRMLS_CC)`

```
/* {{{ proto bool session_regenerate_id([bool delete_old_session])
   Update the current session id with a newly generated one. If delete_old_session is set to true, remove the old session. */
static PHP_FUNCTION(session_regenerate_id)
{
    zend_bool del_ses = 0;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "|b", &del_ses) == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }

    if (SG(headers_sent) && PS(use_cookies)) {
        php_error_docref(NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_WARNING, "Cannot regenerate session id - headers already sent");
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }

    if (PS(session_status) == php_session_active) {
        if (PS(id)) {
            if (del_ses && PS(mod)->s_destroy(&PS(mod_data), PS(id) TSRMLS_CC) == FAILURE) {
                php_error_docref(NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_WARNING, "Session object destruction failed");
                RETURN_FALSE;
            }
            efree(PS(id));
            PS(id) = NULL;
        }

        PS(id) = PS(mod)->s_create_sid(&PS(mod_data), NULL TSRMLS_CC);
        if (PS(id)) {
            PS(send_cookie) = 1;
            php_session_reset_id(TSRMLS_C);
            RETURN_TRUE;
        } else {
            PS(id) = STR_EMPTY_ALLOC();
        }
    }
    RETURN_FALSE;
}
```

**PS_DESTROY_FUNC**

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/mod_files.c

Note `VCWD_UNLINK` which is a command to remove the file from disk.

```
PS_DESTROY_FUNC(files)
{
    char buf[MAXPATHLEN];
    PS_FILES_DATA;

    if (!ps_files_path_create(buf, sizeof(buf), data, key)) {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    if (data->fd != -1) {
        ps_files_close(data);

        if (VCWD_UNLINK(buf) == -1) {
            /* This is a little safety check for instances when we are dealing with a regenerated session
             * that was not yet written to disk. */
            if (!VCWD_ACCESS(buf, F_OK)) {
                return FAILURE;
            }
        }
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `header("Location: $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]");` need to be `header("Location: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']");` ? Or is that just something stupid.

EDIT:

According to PHP.net you should use the `delete_old_session` parameter. Have a look [HERE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php)

Comment: Downvote???????????????? Very noob, such idiots, wow. +1 For me because I wanted to give the same answer. You cannot use a constant you didnt define in place of a string. Besides that, it allows header injection and is a big security issue. But better use it like this: `header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);`

Comment: I setup a demonstration why this answer is important: http://blog.flowl.info/2014/cant-put-array-variables-right-string/

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents: a user (whether or not logged in) is using the site during a certain time, which is usually called a "session". Would it be a problem to always start a session and keep a session variable to see if someone is authenticated. Right now it seems you try to only start a session if someone is logged in, which adds more overhead than just starting a session and checking a variable for the same behavior.

If you keep the session timeout low, someone is automaticly logged out. Depending on the site traffic, you can set the GC to kick in more often or less often. (see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor)

If the harddisk is a bottleneck for sessions (too much empy session files etc.), create a small RAMdisk to store session information on.